# CloneZilla - Overwrote or Corrupted System Partition

Tags: partitioning, clonezilla

My friend was using CloneZilla to mirror his HDD (Windows 7).

- He selected **Partition to Partition**
- He selected **Source: Primary Partition (C:)**
- Then he accidentally selected **Destination: System Partition**

CloneZilla showed some errors that the destination partition was not large enough and stopped, but when he went to boot his computer it said **"Missing Operating System"**.

We removed the HDD and plugged it into another computer via SATA to USB. The HDD appears in Device Manager, but we cannot access it from File Explorer. We can also see it in Disk Management, but there are no partitions.

What should we do?